Unable to upload to s3 with presigned URL
I'm trying to upload an object to s3 bucket through HTTP PUT with the presigned-url returned from S3.getSignedUrl(). However I received the error exception while calling s3 with unknown operation: Unable to parse request (not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0), invalid XML received. Any idea why this happened? Am I missing some headers? I'm using localstack s3 for prototyping.

This issue looks similar as AWS S3 giving error "exception during call chain: Unable to parse request (not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0), invalid XML received:"
I don't know exactly how you are creating your S3 client and how/where you are generating your pre-signed URL, and from where it would need to be available. But you can take a look at the response of the linked question which should help!
